# jQuery .change() fire on radio select by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a jQuery .change() event listener to hide/show divs. 
If I select a radio button by

```
$('#Radio1').prop('checked',true);
```

The listener doesn't fire. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't fire the handler for a change event. You'll need to call .trigger() on the select.

```
$('#Radio1').prop('checked',true).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. I didn't know that function.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use jQuery's trigger method:

```
 $('#Radio1').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it manually:

```
$('#Radio1').trigger('change');
```

or an even shorter version:

```
$('#Radio1').change();
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to trigger your radio button change status :

```
 $("#Radio1").trigger("change");
```

or

```
$("#Radio1").change();
```

and catch it

```
$("#Radio1").change(function () {

});
```

Answer (score -5):

```
$('#Radio1').click(function() {

});
```